# Does PyPy's garbage collector need to stop the world?

Tags: python, pypy

I'm a Java developer so I sometimes need to optimize JVM arguments to improve GC performance(for example, reduce the time of STW).

Recently I tried to introduce Python to my new web project, and I decided to use PyPy as Python interpreter. My question is how does PyPy's garbage collector work? Does it also need to stop the world?

I've done some search but there are not so many docs about PyPy's GC mechanism.

Comment: https://rpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/garbage_collection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that pypy (4.0.1 at least) use the Minimark GC by default.

http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/gc_info.html

https://rpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/garbage_collection.html#minimark-gc

Answer (score 4):

PyPy GC does not stop the world, it's an incremental garbage collector.